# Is it possible to configure thymeleaf to render html from database?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Instead of rendering html files from resource folder i want thymeleaf to render some html string fetched from the database. I have been looking into the thymeleaf libraries, but no luck!

Comment: Yes, you can do this but there is no built in way.  I think you'd probably implement `AbstractTemplateResolver` and put your logic to retrieve the template from the database in the `resolveTemplate` method.  In the `TemplateResolution` that you return, you can use a `StringTemplateResource` to return your template as a String selected from the database.

Comment: Thanks Metroids. we can use the StringTemplateResolver and provide it to the TemplateEngine, it will do  the work. Thanks again.